# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' when i think code is corect

Tags: python

```
character_age = "13"
character_name = "lado"
print(   + character_name +    " really like coding")
print( " but she didnt learn to type until "  + character_age +  " years old. ")
```

i was trying to learn variables in python when thos error came up

```
PS D:\freecodecamp> & C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe d:/freecodecamp/2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\freecodecamp\2.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(+_character_name+   " really like coding, ")
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Comment: `print(character_name+" really like coding")`. The could should be like this. You had extra `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `+` in your first print statement. Use this: `print(character_name + " really like coding")`

Comment: Thanks a lot...i was trying to solve it since one hour...it worked now

Comment: If a question is correct and usable, click the checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate a correct answer.

Comment: I did that now....